# Linux - Tailing the time

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

So, to tail a log and watch it in real-time, one uses

```
tail -f <filename>
```

but what if you want to follow something else? Follow here is not really accurate I suppose, more like refresh the same set of data repeatedly.. is this possible?

I'm thinking of things like this: if you want to watch to see when a file moves from one folder to another, say as part of a function run through cron, you can use

```
ls -lR
```

repeatedly, but what I'm thinking of is something like the equivalent of:

```
ls -lR | tail -f
```

or

```
date | tail -f
```

to waste time watching the clock tick.

Is there anything like this, or is that just the limitation of the console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean [watch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) command?

```
watch -n 1 'date'
```

This way you can watch the time change for every second. Default is 2 seconds.

Comment: `watch -n 1 date` would suffice.

Comment: Is this just for time or can it be used for anything? Can one watch a folder every 2 seconds?

Comment: @spuriosity It's for any command.

Comment: Beautiful stuff! Thanks! :) -- have to wait 3 mins before I can mark as answered